# Turning for loop to apply

Tags: r, apply

I have tried to understand how apply works but having a hard time understaning how to use it. 
I have a df frame called *SSO9* that is 172*92. Its only 1:s or 0:s as elements in it.

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 ...
1      0    1
0      1    1
0      0    1
.
.
```

I now want to take each permutation there is when choosing three columns and take the rowsum. Meaning first the first, second and third column and take the row sum and save it in a new df, then first secound and four and so on. Meaning this will reslut in 92 choose 3 = 125580 column.

```
ds=data.frame(rowSums(SSO9[,c(1,2,3)]))

for(i in 1:90){
  for(j in (i+1):91){ 
    for(k in (j+1):92){
    temp<-data.frame(rowSums(SSO9[,c(i,j,k)]))
    colnames(temp)<-(paste(colnames(SSO9[i]),colnames(SSO9[c(j)]),paste(colnames(SSO9[k]),sep=",")))
    ds=cbind(ds,temp) 
    rm(temp)
    }
  }
}
ds$rowSums.SSO9...c.1..2..3...<-NULL
```

This code work but is kind of slow, so I would like to try to use apply insted of 3 for loops, but I have no idea how to make use of apply, especially when I want all the permutations. Also as you can see I create the df *ds* by taking the rowsum of the first three columns then deleting it just to get the dimentions right, but there probably is a better way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would suggest is storing the input as a matrix, since it only has 1s and 0s, and these kinds of numerical operations will generally be more performant on matrices than data.frames.

Here's how this can be accomplished using [`combn()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/combn.html), [`apply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html), and [`rowSums()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html):

```
set.seed(1);
NR <- 172; NC <- 92; SSO9 <- matrix(sample(0:1,NR*NC,replace=T),NR,dimnames=list(NULL,paste0('Col',1:NC)));
head(SSO9[,1:10]);
##      Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Col10
## [1,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    1     0
## [2,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1     1
## [3,]    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0     0
## [4,]    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    1     0
## [5,]    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1     1
## [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1     0
system.time({
    comb <- combn(ncol(SSO9),3);
    res <- apply(comb,2,function(cis) rowSums(SSO9[,cis]));
    colnames(res) <- apply(comb,2,function(cis) paste(colnames(SSO9)[cis],collapse=','));
});
##    user  system elapsed
##   3.422   0.203   3.626
dim(res);
## [1]    172 125580
head(res[,1:10]);
##      Col1,Col2,Col3 Col1,Col2,Col4 Col1,Col2,Col5 Col1,Col2,Col6 Col1,Col2,Col7 Col1,Col2,Col8 Col1,Col2,Col9 Col1,Col2,Col10 Col1,Col2,Col11 Col1,Col2,Col12
## [1,]              2              2              1              1              1              2              2               1               2               2
## [2,]              0              1              1              0              1              1              1               1               0               0
## [3,]              1              1              1              2              2              2              1               1               2               2
## [4,]              2              3              3              2              2              3              3               2               3               3
## [5,]              1              2              2              1              1              1              2               2               1               1
## [6,]              3              3              3              2              3              3              3               2               2               2
```

Also note that these are [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), not [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), since order does not matter.

Comment: Wow, thanks :D Will take some time to try to understand everything and so before "accept" this ansewer :) 

Aaa, my bad then , combinations ^^

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any questions. :)

Comment: The third argument to `apply()` must be a [lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), which in R can be defined using `function(a,b,…) …`. `apply()` runs the function once for every index across the margin(s) (aka dimension(s)), passing the matrix (or array) slice as the sole argument of each invocation. Thus, in this case, `cis` is the column vector of `comb` for the current invocation, since we specified margin=2. I used the name `cis` to mean "column indexes", since `comb` contains one combination of (`SSO9`) column indexes per (`comb`) column.

Comment: Okey. Think I start to understand it at least :) Have to try and play around with it to see how it works. 
But thanks for the help with my problem!